# jQuery Text Slideshow on Two lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

So what I need to do is this: Have a text slideshow that does an alpha fade in between each text item. The tricky part is to have it going on two lines with each changing opposite the last. Top change, wait, bottom change, wait, top change, etc. Here is the layout in text and below that is some code I found.

STATIC HEADER TEXT HERE

Line One Text Goes Here

Line Two Text Goes Here

MORE STATIC TEXT HERE

HTML:

```
<div id="textslide">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var quotes = new Array();

quotes[0] = "quote1";
quotes[1] = "quote2";
quotes[2] = "quote3";
quotes[3] = "quote4";
quotes[4] = "quote5";
console.log(quotes);
var counter = 0;

function loop() {
    if (counter > 4) counter = 0;
    $('#textslide p:first').text(quotes[counter]);
    counter++;
    console.log(counter);
    setTimeout(loop, 500);
}
loop();
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kylebellamy/1esmu097/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with. Hope you need a similar functionality.

```js
var quotes = new Array();
var quotes2 = new Array();

quotes[0] = "quote1";
quotes[1] = "quote2";
quotes[2] = "quote3";
quotes[3] = "quote4";
quotes[4] = "quote5";

quotes2[0] = "second quote1";
quotes2[1] = "second quote2";
quotes2[2] = "second quote3";
quotes2[3] = "second quote4";
quotes2[4] = "second quote5";

var counter = 0;
var counter2 = 0;

function loop() {
  if (counter > 4) counter = 0;
  $('#textslide p:first').text(quotes[counter]);
  $('#textslide p:first').hide();
  $("#textslide p:first").fadeIn("slow");
  counter++;
  setTimeout(loop2, 1000);
}

function loop2() {
  if (counter2 > 4) counter2 = 0;
  $('#textslide p:last').text(quotes2[counter2]);
  $('#textslide p:last').hide();
  $("#textslide p:last").fadeIn("slow");
  counter2++;
  setTimeout(loop, 1000);
}
loop();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textslide">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it better to have the two separate functions or the combined one that was first posted as an answer by @wallek876 ?

Comment: @kylebellamy Actually using a single loop will be better if you are not going to perform different apporaches for showing the content inside each `<p>` tag. I have edited my answer with an animation too.

Comment: Ah! I see that now. Yeah, that is what I was looking for. I love this place, I learn something new every day.

Comment: Glad to help :) Yeah most of the time Stackoverflow has better solutions than which are there in the original sources.

Comment: Yeah, just make sure you word it extremely carefully or the hammer comes down hard. lol

Comment: Hehe yeah that is always true.! :D

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want:

html:

```
<div id="textslide">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var quotes = new Array();

quotes[0] = "You can do anything, but not everything";
quotes[1] = "Perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away";
quotes[2] = "You miss 100 percent of the shots you never take";
quotes[3] = "You must be the change you wish to see in the world";
quotes[4] = "Always forgive your enemies; nothing annoys them so much";
quotes[5] = "Those who believe in telekinetics, raise my hand";

var counter = 0;

function loop() {

    if (counter > 5) counter = 0;
    $('#textslide p').eq(counter % 2).text(quotes[counter]);
    $('#textslide p').eq(counter % 2).fadeTo(500, 100).delay(1000);
    $('#textslide p').eq(counter % 2).fadeTo(500, 0);
    counter++;
    setTimeout(loop, 2000);
}
loop();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wallek876/4djyen76/4/)

```js
var quotes = new Array();

quotes[0] = "You can do anything, but not everything";
quotes[1] = "Perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away";
quotes[2] = "You miss 100 percent of the shots you never take";
quotes[3] = "You must be the change you wish to see in the world";
quotes[4] = "Always forgive your enemies; nothing annoys them so much";
quotes[5] = "Those who believe in telekinetics, raise my hand";

var counter = 0;

function loop() {

    if (counter > 5) counter = 0;
    $('#textslide p').eq(counter % 2).text(quotes[counter]);
    $('#textslide p').eq(counter % 2).fadeTo(500, 100).delay(1000);
    $('#textslide p').eq(counter % 2).fadeTo(500, 0);
    counter++;
    setTimeout(loop, 2000);
}
loop();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textslide">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nearly perfect!! Such a small change! Thanks.
So where do I work an animation into that loop?

Comment: For instance the fade out and in of each text item:
.animate({opacity: 0}, {duration: 700})

Or is loop the wrong approach?

Comment: @kylebellamy for animation there is no difference you can choose the one you like most, i added one in the example.